# Convergence of sequence of absolute values proof verification (Real Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'm doing an exercise in Abbott's Understanding Analysis that asks to prove that if the limit of the sequence $(b_n)$ is b, then the sequence of absolute values $|b_n|$ converges to |b|. It seems fairly obvious that this would be true, but the proof in the solution manual makes use of the triangle inequality whereas mine doesn't. I'm still relatively unfamiliar with what is considered a valid proof, so if someone could let me know if my proof is incorrect, (and why, if it is) that would be great.

My proof:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Then, pick $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|b_n-b|< \epsilon$ when $n \geq N$.

If $b < 0$, then $|b_n|$ for $n \geq N$ must be equal to $-b_n$ because $|b_n|$ is within the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $b$. Additionally, since $b < 0$, $|b|=-b$. This implies that $||b_n|-|b||=|-1||b_n-b|$, so our choice of $N$ for $|b_n-b|< \epsilon$ still works because the inequality remains unchanged.

If $b>0$, then $|b_n|=b_n$ for $n \geq N$ because $|b_n|$ is within the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $b$. Additionally, if $b > 0$, then $|b|=b$. This implies that our original inequality demonstrating our choice of $N$ remains unchanged, so our choice of $N$ for $|b_n-b|< \epsilon$ still works.

If $b=0$, then $|b_n-b|=|b_n|< \epsilon$, and since $||b_n||=|b_n|$, the original inequality remains unchanged and our choice of $N$ still works, just like in the previous two arguments.

Are there any logical gaps/assumptions/etc.? I've been trying to make my proofs as rigorous as possible, so if they don't align with the proof given in the book, I get a little unsure.

Comment: Excellent work. The quicker kill uses the reverse triangle inequality.